# How can I launch the Samsung RTL Client JNLP to use adb? (instead of the new web Client)

Tags: android, client, adb, samsung

I want to **debug** my Android app for some bug that happens only on some Samsung devices so I tried using [Samsung Remote Test Lab](https://developer.samsung.com/remote-test-lab).

But I want to debug using `adb` or `Android Studio` and the Web Client the devices launch [here](https://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlHelpDevice.action?gid=2000&pageord=5) doesn't seem to have ever heard of such thing.

There is some `adb` [documentation](https://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlHelpDevice.action?gid=2000&pageord=1) for some Java Client that you would download as JNLP but I cannot find how to download that file? I tried Windows and Mac, a few devices, on Chrome and Firefox too.

Was the debug feature just dropped or what am I missing?

Comment: JNLP = Java Web Start. This tehcnology only works with Oracle Java 8 (no OpenJDK, no version newer than Java 8).

Comment: Fine with me... but still I want to launch a client with adb capability, how to do this?